# Angularjs checkbox checked enables input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-disabled

I'm kinda new in AngularJS and my issue is:

I have a loop like this:

```
 <body ng-app="ngToggle">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="btn in btns" class="here" value="{{btn.value}}">

        <input type="text" class="uncheck" disabled>
    </div>
</body>
```

One of those checkboxes has a value of "OTHER", and what I need to do is: when the checkbox with the "OTHER" value is checked it remove the disabled attribute from the `<input type="text" class="uncheck" disabled>`

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('ngToggle', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.btns = [
        {value:'one'},
        {value:'two'},
        {value:'other'}
        ];
}]);
```

Hope someone can help me,
Thanks.

Comment: You should be using `radio` buttons I guess..

Comment: I can't because more than one option can be selected @Rayon

Comment: fyi the "ng" prefix for controllers is conventionally used by stuff that is provided by angularjs by default. Best to not use it in custom components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `ng-change` directive and test value of `other` checkbox in `forEach-loop`

```js
angular.module('ngToggle', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.disabled = true;
      $scope.btns = [{
        value: 'one'
      }, {
        value: 'two'
      }, {
        value: 'other'
      }];
      $scope.onChange = function() {
        $scope.btns.forEach(function(btn) {
          if (btn.value === 'other' && btn.status === true) {
            $scope.disabled = false;
          } else {
            $scope.disabled = true;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="ngToggle">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="btn in btns" class="here" ng-model='btn.status' ng-change='onChange()'>

    <input type="text" class="uncheck" ng-disabled='disabled'>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @rayon thanks for the answer, this work great, base on your answer i manage to make it work, but now lets say we have several checkboxes loops followed by an input field, and every time the "other" checkbox is checked it will enable the followed input field, please check my next question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37659974/angularjs-scope-with-parameter), Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of ng-models. Please avoild using "values attribute" as well in AngularJS. The alternative for values is "ng-init". Well anyway, here is a working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="ngToggle">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <p ng-repeat="btn in btns">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="btn.bool" value="ss"  class="here" > {{ btn.value }}
        </p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="textModel" class="uncheck" ng-disabled="other.bool">
        <p>{{ other.bool  }} -- {{textModel  }}</p> 
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('ngToggle', [])
            .controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
                $scope.btns = [
                {value:'one', bool:false},
                {value:'two', bool:true},
                {value:'other', bool:true}
                ];
                $scope.otherBool = $scope.btns[2]['bool'];
                $scope.btns.map(function(obj){
                  //alert(JSON.stringify(obj))
                  if((obj.value) == 'other'){
                    $scope.other = obj;
                  }
                });
        }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

YOu can check it in plunker as well: http://plnkr.co/edit/GODfWbhlWvzjLKHFcEYs?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```js
angular.module('ngToggle', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.btns = [
        {value:'one',name:"one"},
        {value:'two',name:'two'},
        {value:'other',name:'other'}
        ];
      
       $scope.disable=true;
      
      $scope.check = function(value){
        if(value == "'other'")
          $scope.disable = false;
        else
           $scope.disable=true;
      }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ngToggle">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <div  ng-repeat="btn in btns">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="btn.value" ng-true-value="'{{btn.value}}'" ng-change="check(btn.value)" >{{btn.name}}
      </div>
        <input type="text" class="uncheck" ng-disabled='disable'>
    </div>
</div>
```