# Angularjs $scope with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I'm new in Angular and I can't achieve something really simple, lets say we have several checkbox input loops followed by an `input` text field like this:

```
<body ng-app="ngToggle">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="btn in btns" ng-model="changing" ng-change="change(btn.value, 'other')" class="here" value="{{btn.value}}">

        <input type="text" class="uncheck" ng-disabled="other">


    <!-- Here comes the other one -->

       <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="btn in btns" ng-model="changing" ng-change="change(btn.value, 'other2')" class="here" value="{{btn.value}}">

       <input type="text" class="uncheck" ng-disabled="other2">
    </div>
</body>
```

And the idea in here is this: once the checkbox with value "other" is checked it will enable the corresponding text field determinate in the field parameter of the `change` function, so I develop a function `change(value, field)` and works like this:

```
     $scope.btns = [
        {value:'one'},
        {value:'two'},
        {value:'other'}
    ];

   $scope.other = true;
   $scope.other2 = true;

   $scope.change = function(value, field) {
    if(value == 'other'){
        if($scope.field == false){
        $scope.field = true;
      } else {
        $scope.field = false;
      }
    }
  };
```

But the problem is, this does not work, I don't know if I making this in the right way, the `$scope.field` is the problem, how can I pass a parameter to the `$scope`

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: `$scope.field` does not seem to be initialized anywhere

Comment: Exactly, I'm trying to put the value in the passed parameter in the `$scope`, per example if I put something like this: `change(one)`, the scope will become `$scope.one` because that's the FIELD parameter @Guillaume

Comment: right, I did not understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-model` with the checkbox, then use `ng-disabled` to listen to that model belonging to the checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Other" ng-model="myCheckboxes['other']" />
<input type="text" ng-disabled="myCheckboxes['other']" />
```